# how to use dynamic variables in object value?

Tags: javascript, object

is it possible to use dynamic variables in object value? (not property)

```
errors = { 'small_age':`${age} is too small`}

age = 17;
if (age < 18) {
   alert(errors.small_age)
}
```

Comment: You have to declare and define `age` before the string template is evaluated.

Comment: You might want to look into [template tag functions.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals#tagged_templates)

Comment: function check_age(age){
  if (age < 18) {
    errors = { 'small_age':`${age} is too small`}
     alert(errors.small_age); // here works correctly
 } 
}

check_age(17);
check_age(15);

// is there a way to declare errors object globally? because there are hundreds error messages in errors object that not only for age check

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript is a [Dynamic Programming Language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming_language). (Read more about [Dynamic Type Systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_system#DYNAMIC))

Your code is correct (even though you haven't included the code to define `var age`). Here is the [fiddle for it](https://jsfiddle.net/e2069j5a/). Be vary of what version of JavaScript you use that supports [Template Literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals).

Comment: yes thanks, but i want to declare all errors messages (hundreds) in one object once globally. not to separete each one for each functions. is there a way?  sth like https://jsfiddle.net/akin/qwe3ug6o/15/

Comment: Your code is correct. Just extend it and include more messages (like the fiddle you shared): 
errors = { 
 'small_age':`${age} is too small`,
 'too_heavy':`${weight} is too much`,
 'too_short':`${heigth} is too short`,
//... there are thousand item
}
You could also add them dynamically in a loop. Like say: `errors['mymessage'] = 'this is a new error';` after initializing the `error` object.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/rvunbm1t/ Please review this for example. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a function as the value in an object and then pass the variable that you want to use as a parameter, that way it's more obvious what value is being used on the error message.

```
const errors = { 'small_age': (age) => `${age} is too small` }

const age = 17;
if (age < 18) {
   alert(errors.small_age(age))
}
```

Expected alert message

```
17 is too small
```

Comment: Thank you Diego, yes that was what I wanted and worked perfectly...

Comment: @AkinZeman Glad it worked! Would really appreciate if you marked the answer as accepted :)

Answer (score 0):

thanks to @Diego_Sanches, I solved like that [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/akin/qwe3ug6o/33/)

```
const errors = { 
  'too_young': (n) => `${n} is too young`,
  'too_short': (n) => `${n} is too short`,
  'too_heavy': (n) => `${n} is too heavy`,
  //there thousant err msgs, and didnot want to seperate each of them for related functions...  
  }

function check_age(n){
  if (n < 18) alert(errors.too_young(n)) 
}

function check_height(n){
  if (n < 180) alert(errors.too_short(n))
}

function check_weight(n){
  if (n > 90) alert(errors.too_heavy(n))
}

check_age(17);
check_height(150);
check_weight(120);
```